# MS Access expression iff Or

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to create an expression that returns the value of [Hood Cut Size] if enclosure is "Full Enclosure" or "Back Box only".

I know that the following expression won't work because the true part of the iif statement is set to a field, how can i go about returning [Hood Cut Size] if the values are met.

```
IIf([Enclosure]="Full Enclosure" Or [Enclosure]="Back Box only",[Hood Cut Size],"FALSE")
```

Thanks

Comment: In what way is that not working for you, do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have would work fine, or more concisely:

```
 IIf([Enclosure] In ("Full Enclosure","Back Box only"),[Hood Cut Size],"FALSE")
```

Comment: "The expression could not be saved because of its result type"

Comment: Try with `Cstr([Hood Cut Size])`

Comment: Now it says it cannot be used in a calculated column. Can you not return a field instead of it being a "value".

Comment: I've done it now, instead of using Cstr just use Str thanks anyway!

Comment: Using Str in stead of CStr will add a leading Space to the result string.

Comment: I've seen but there is no function for CStr on the newest/the version of access I'm using. Its not allowing the expression to work.

Comment: Trim$ seems to remove the space.